# eMule cannot create Incoming Files directory

Tags: windows-7, emule

I have installed eMule on Windows 7. When I start eMule, I will receive the following message:

> Failed to create Incoming Files directory 'C:\Program
>   Files\eMule\Incoming' - Access is denied

I get a similar message for "C:\Program Files\eMule\Temp" and "Failed to initialize cryptokeys - secure ident disabled". It looks like Windows 7 does not allow eMule to do such operations. How can I give eMule the right to do what it needs?

Answer (score 2):

Probably by:

- (**recommended**) setting the Incoming directory elsewhere (outside of `Program Files`)

[image]

Change the paths in the settings

- or (*not recommended*)  launching Emule with Administrator rights
  (because of [protected mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462%28VS.85%29.aspx) requiring High Integrity Access Level (IL) for a process to write in `c:\Program Files`)

[image]

Comment: The second option is much preferable.

Comment: @harrymc: agreed, following your comment, I have switched the order of said solutions. So your comment should read: "the first option is much preferable" ;) )

Answer (score 0):

To make incoming files in eMule work with Windows 7 and Vista, you need to follow these steps:

1. Go to: Control Panel > User Accounts and Family Safety > User Accounts
2. Click *Change User Account Control settings*
3. Drag the scrollbar down to *Never notify*

After that you can use eMule to download in Windows 7 and Vista.